# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'xxxxxxxx'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a logic in Django to check if all the `TabularInline` items are saved before saving the model itself. here is the code am using:

```py
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            item_count_in_origin = instance.prc_item.quantity
            print(item_count_in_origin)
            if instance.quantity > item_count_in_origin:
                messages.error(request, 'Quantity is higher than origin branch.')
                return
            else:
                for item in instances:
                    if item.id is not None:
                        item.close()
                    else:
            formset.save()

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.transfer_items.all().count() != 0:
            user = request.user
            if self.save_formset:
                if not change:
                    obj.solicitor = user
                    obj.date_solicited = datetime.now()
                    created_status = Status.objects.get(name=StatusEnum.CREATED)
                    obj.status = created_status
                return super(TransferenceAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Quantity is higher than origin branch.')
            return
```

when the condition `if instance.quantity > item_count_in_origin:` it works right and bring back an error, but when it is false and we go the part of

```py
                for item in instances:
                    if item.id is not None:
                        item.close()
                    else:
                        formset.save()
```

it fails with the error `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'xxxxxxxx'.`

**UPDATE**

I've changed `if item.id is not None:` to `if item.id is None:` to make sure that `item.close()` run only on open but not saved instances.

And the error became `'TransferRequestItem' object has no attribute 'close'` I think this is the wrong way to close an open instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838433/save-prohibited-to-prevent-data-loss-due-to-unsaved-related-object)

Comment: You're calling `formset.save` more than once; there's i loop inside

Comment: got it out of the loop and it gives the same error