# ValueError at /register/ save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'

Tags: django, django-views

I am building a site in django but my registration is not working whenever i click submit i face this error i am setting up a profile for an user i am not sure this the right way so if there are better ways to do this plese do comment

The suggested question uses a primary key i am using a one to one field
The code was working untill i added an function to edit user profile functionality can it cause problems ?

```
ValueError at /register/
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.
```

Please Help , also i am a beginner a brief answer would be very much apperciated
Here is the view :

```
def register(request):
    profiles = UserProfilePage()
    forms = CreateUser()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profiles = UserProfilePage(request.POST, request.FILES)
        forms = CreateUser(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid() and profiles.is_valid():
            user = forms.save()
            profile = profiles.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='user')
            user.groups.add(group)
            username = forms.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Account was successfully created for ' + username)
            return redirect('Login_Page')
    ctx = {
        'forms': forms,
        'profiles': profiles,
    }
    return render(request, 'Register.html', ctx)
```

Forms:

```
class CreateUser(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'This is your identification value so it must be unique'
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        if not commit:
            user.save()

        return user


class UserProfilePage(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['Nick_Name', 'Profile_pic']
        help_texts = {
            'Nick_Name': 'This will act as your display name',
        }

    Profile_pic = CloudinaryFileField(
        options={
            'folder': 'Profile/'
        })

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfilePage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['Nick_Name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['Profile_pic'].widget.attrs['onchange'] = 'profile(event)'
        self.fields['Profile_pic'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Nick_Name = models.CharField(default="Hey", max_length=250)
    Profile_pic = CloudinaryField('Profile_Pic', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838433/save-prohibited-to-prevent-data-loss-due-to-unsaved-related-object)

Comment: Why are you saving only when commit is False in your CreateUser form?

Comment: Because i get when it is true i get an error saying i am saving the user twice

Comment: Remove the `save` method completely from your form, you don't need to override it

Comment: Alright thanks a lot should i delete the save function too ?

Comment: Delete the `CreateUser.save` method/function, it's not necessary

Comment: I used the save because of some tutorials but can you tell me why the save function is used please ?

Comment: I am getting this error now please help

Comment: IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: I think i found the reason why it is not working the docs say i have to save the user then only i can acess it for one to one but the error is not allowing me to save it